# How to return a view which's model gets serialised resulting in the error string greater than maxJsonLength

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-mvc-5, max, size

I'm getting the "the length of the string  exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property".
When returning a view from my controller, which is then serialized by razor.

i.e.
return View(viewModel);

and in the view

```
@{
    var javaScriptSearilizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var serializedViewModel = javaScriptSearilizer.Serialize(Model);
}
```

Any way past this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is.

Remove the

```
@{
    var javaScriptSearilizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var serializedViewModel = javaScriptSearilizer.Serialize(Model);
}
```

and when the Document is ready, do this.

```
serializedViewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```